# Add OutputFormatters for selected Action only

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

There is an option to add new OutputFormatters globally for all controllers, but how to add OutputFormatters for selected Action?

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
    {
        options.OutputFormatters.Insert(0, new CsvOutputFormatter(new CsvFormatterOptions { CsvDelimiter = "," }));
    })
```

I have found IResultFilter and it has the method OnResultExecuting where formatted can be added. After that, I can decorate the Action with a new ResultFilter attribute. Is this the correct way to assign custom formats for certain actions?

```
public class CsvResultFilter : IResultFilter
{
    public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (context.Result is ObjectResult objectResult)
        {
            var csvOutputFormatter = new CsvOutputFormatter(new CsvFormatterOptions { CsvDelimiter = "," });

            objectResult.Formatters.Add(csvOutputFormatter);
        }
    }

    public void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

Another problem I am facing is if I decorate Action with attribute I get an exception that the service is not registered.

```
[ServiceFilter(typeof(CsvResultFilter))]
public async Task<ActionResult> Statistic([FromQuery] ExportStatisticParams model, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
}
```

If I register it in  `builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>             options.Filters.Add(typeof(CsvResultFilter)))` the CsvResultFilter filter gets executed on all actions.

Comment: Does it work? Then yes, it's the right way.

Comment: @DavidG It doesn't, I have updated my question. I don't know how to decorate action and register filter to be executed for only selected action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of things you need to do to make this work. If you really need to use `ServiceFilterAttribute` then you need to ensure:

1. The output formatter type registered in the DI container (e.g. `builder.Services.AddSingleton<CsvOutputFormatter>();`
2. The formatter must also implement `IFilterMetadata`.

However, there's another way which I think is a little cleaner. You can create your own attribute that inherits from `ActionFilterAttribute`. Something like this:

```
public class CsvOutputAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (context.Result is ObjectResult objectResult)
        {
            // You could also use DI here with 
            // context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<CsvOutputFormatter>();
            var formatter = new CsvOutputFormatter(...);

            //objectResult.Formatters.Clear(); //<- You may want to add this?
            objectResult.Formatters.Add(formatter);
        }
    }
}
```

And decorate your action or controller with it:

```
[CsvOutput]
public IActionResult MyAction()
{
    return new ObjectResult("hello");
}
```